# Why is NMI signal edge triggered , whereas INTR signal level triggered in x86 processor?

Tags: x86, interrupt, microprocessors

What is advantage of using a particular type(level/edge)for a certain type of signal ?

Comment: INTR has a "complex" protocol, when asserted the CPU will respond on the bus with an ACK and the interrupt controller will then send the interrupt vector. This means that asserting INTR won't cause the CPU to jump to an interrupt vector immediately. NMI is instead much simpler: when triggered the CPU jumps to INT 02h. Since it cannot be masked, if it were level triggered the CPU would jump to INT 02h multiple times until the NMI signals is de-asserted. In the INTR case, this is handled by the PIC (and the more complex protocol). See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/21965)

Comment: Thanks @MargaretBloom . Does INTR works only with hardware interrupts? I remember something like INTA signal( i think it's a control signal for interrupts) gets generated. This goes to interrupt controller and then a interrupt vector is generated. This vector gives IP and CS of ISR , which has instructions to generate output for that particular interrupt. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: INTR was a physical pin on the CPU die, it was made for requesting interrupts from devices. The rest is right in the great picture.